Inconsistent Video Results from Facebook Graph API in React Native Expo App
I'm developing a React Native Expo app, and I'm using the Facebook Graph API to fetch videos from my Facebook page and stream them within the app using WebView. However, I'm encountering an issue where I sometimes receive two different versions of the videos when making the same API call. This inconsistency is causing confusion, and I can't determine the root cause.
When I fetch the videos using the Graph API and display them in a WebView, I sometimes get two different versions of the same video content. This inconsistency is not predictable, and I can't figure out why it's happening.
Every thing works but the end result it changes randomly(how the videos gets displayed)
Image1: This version i Like it
Image2: This one is not so much
The first one lets me change the quality and play the video in that screen, while the second one goes into fullscreen mode when clicked and plays the videos with no additional controls
